# Limit characters to the end of the input text box

Tags: html

When I type in a input text box I can carry on typing past the end of the text box,  I think have to use the arrow keys to move through what is in it.

I want to limit the characters to not go past the end of the text box. 
I tried the maxlength="x" but as different characters take up more room than others, i.e AAAAA is longer than aaaaa, so I can't be as precise as what I'd like to be.

Comment: So you want to allow typing in, say, 50 "I", but only 20 "M"? That's… unusual.

Comment: use a monospace font-family where all the character will take the same space

Comment: Very unusual... How does the user know how many characters he/she can enter in the textbox?

Comment: No I just want the text inside the text area to not go past the end, whether it's 22 A characters or 26 a characters, this is why I don't want to use the maxlength property.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some monospace font (every character has the same width)

Comment: Still the characters have different width

Comment: Yeah but its still better. Best way to do it is to use monospace font

Comment: It does not limit anything though. That is what the op asked for.